# Best way to convert a decimal number to next non-decimal number in PHP

Tags: php

Example: if a number is: `3.2` then it will become `4`

round($variable), function only do this, if the decimal value is 0.6 or higher.

Is their any function in PHP to do so? Currently, i am using this code to do what i want:

```
    if ($totalpages > round($totalpages))  // If the number is less than 0.06
{ 
$round1 = round($totalpages); 
$round2 = $totalpages-round($totalpages); 
$round3 = 1-$round2; 
$round4 = $totalpages+$round3; 
$totalpages = $round4; // 
}
else 
    $totalpages = round($totalpages);
```

Is their any better way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looking for `ceil()`

> ceil — Round fractions up
>
> Description
>
> float ceil ( float $value ) Returns the next highest integer value by
>   rounding up value if necessary.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php